# JSON format to show message after jQGrid delete (delGridRow)?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm creating a new jqgrid table, my question is how the response should be formated in JSON to supply response text in [afterSubmit event](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#delgridrow)? 
For example, is it formated like this: `{'response': true}` ?

Anyway, i need this to show message to user whether the record(s) is been successfully deleted or not. Like "Record(s) has been deleted" or "Record(s) cannot be deleted".
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can format it for your needs. I personally use something like

```
[
    {"success": true}, 
    {"response": "Record has been deleted"}
]
```

The details are in how you read the message and handle it in the response.

So in your `afterSubmit` event function, you can deal with the data as follows

```
afterSubmit : function(response, postdata) 
{ 
    var data = JSON.parse(response.responseText); 

    if(data[0].success){

        // do stuff for success;

    } else {

        // do stuff for failure;

    }
};
```

Comment: i'm trying your code, using chrome my response look like this: 
`[{ "success":true},{"message":"Record has been deleted" }]`

Then in my jqgrid:

`$('#gridprovinsi').jqGrid('delGridRow', row, {
  recreateForm: true,
  reloadAfterSubmit:true,
  closeAfterDelete: true,
  afterSubmit : function(response, postdata) 
  {
   if(response[0].success) {
    alert(response[0].message);
   } 
  }
 });`

But it won't alert any message when I succesfully received that response. Any idea?

Comment: Are you setting the response on your `afterSubmit` call?

Comment: what is the result of this???  `afterSubmit: function(response, postdata){console.log(response);}`

Comment: Anyway, i'm using regular alert like `alert('record has been deleted');` isn't working any idea?

Comment: for testing purposes, you can use either one `alert();` or `console.log();`

Comment: If you mean looking the output at chrome console, then there is nothing written..

Comment: in the Google Chrome [Javascript Console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)

Comment: what is the output of `afterSubmit: function(response, postdata){console.log(response.responseText);}`

Comment: nothing? as in, not even an error? do you have a public service I can test (or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net))?

Comment: I'm testing it in my local server, if you using teamviewer, I can give  you my temporary meeting id. May I?

Comment: I have tried your edit, send output to console.log. But still, nothing appear there..

Comment: sorry, don't have teamviewer. I'm not sure how the `afterSubmit` method is called, but that will contain the answer.

Comment: After modifying server side code, i got this in my console log..
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'regional' of undefined admin_core.js:21
(anonymous function) admin_core.js:21
jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery.js:1046
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery.js:1164
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:435
DOMContentLoaded jquery.js:923`

That's error show up even when I'm not executing delGridRow in jQGrid

Comment: Here is my [admin_core.js](http://pastebin.com/bmzh10Rj)

I'm using jQuery v1.7.1

Comment: that has nothing to do with jqgrid. it's something with your datepicker.

Comment: Ok. anyway I'm using jQgrid v4.3.3. I'm also using twitter bootstrap

Comment: The github repo is using `var result = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');` so try that, and then `console.log(result);`

Comment: Please don't use the comments as an interactive debugger.